# Border spacing and hover effect not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do two things here but can't make either work. I've never played with CSS before so I've just been sitting on jsfiddle for a few hours trying to just make this basic div table

The first thing I'm trying to do is get 30px border spacing working. I've tried to enter it everywhere in the CSS and all the cells are still attached instead of having space between them

The second thing is the hover effect. I would like a message to pop up on each cell, but the way I have it now, when you put your mouse over the cell, it shows the hover effect on the entire row

any help would be appreciated. Here's my current code

```css
.BestSeller {
  border-spacing: 30px;
  display: table;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.BestSellerRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.BestSellerBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.BestSellerCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  padding: 10px;
}

.BestSellerTextBox {
  background-color: #ff9225;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.BestSellerTextBox:hover {
  background-color: #ff9f3f;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.BestSellerOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.BestSellerCell:Hover .BestSellerOverlay {
  height: 50%;
}

.BestSellerOverlayText {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="BestSeller">
  <div class="BestSellerBody">
    <div class="BestSellerRow">
      <div class="BestSellerCell">I Like Eggs<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="BestSellerOverlay">
          <div class="BestSellerOverlayText">Hello World</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test </div>
    </div>
    <div class="BestSellerRow">
      <div class="BestSellerCell">I Like Eggs<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="BestSellerOverlay">
          <div class="BestSellerOverlayText">Why This No Work</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Hi! I've seen you are using `border-collapse: collapse;`. Have you tried using `border-collapse: separated;`? Furthermore, if you remove all those `<br>` that you got, the overlay-text appears correctly. Try using margins and padding instead of just a bunch of breaklines.

Comment: I find it very confusing that you're using `<div> ....</div>` and then in your CSS you turn them into table tags by using `display`. Why not use the normal HTML tags for tables?

Comment: I haven't really used css or  html before. I was just copying random codes I got from websites like divtable.com and editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `border-spacing` work with `border-collapse : separate`. Add that to `.BestSeller` and it will do the work. More refer to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing).

Secondly, you set `.BestSellerOverlay` to `position: absolute`, which is a good start. However, [`absolute` positions the element to its nearest positioned ancestor.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values). If there is no nearest positioned ancestor, it will fallback to the viewport. Which is the result you see, the overlay attached to the bottom to the page. I apply `position: relative` to `.BestSellerCell`, such the overlay will stick to the cell.

```css
.BestSeller {
  display: table;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.BestSellerRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.BestSellerBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.BestSellerCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}


/*==============================================================================
  #BestSellerTextBox
==============================================================================*/

.BestSellerTextBox {
  background-color: #ff9225;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.BestSellerTextBox:hover {
  background-color: #ff9f3f;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*==============================================================================
  #HoverOverlay For Best Selelr
==============================================================================*/

.BestSellerOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.BestSellerCell:Hover .BestSellerOverlay {
  height: 50%;
}

.BestSellerOverlayText {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="BestSeller">
  <div class="BestSellerBody">
    <div class="BestSellerRow">
      <div class="BestSellerCell">
        I Like Eggs<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        <div class="BestSellerOverlay">
          <div class="BestSellerOverlayText">Hello World</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test</div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test</div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="BestSellerRow">
      <div class="BestSellerCell">
        I Like Eggs<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        <div class="BestSellerOverlay">
          <div class="BestSellerOverlayText">Why This No Work</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test</div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test</div>
      <div class="BestSellerCell">This is just a quick test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use [grid.layoutit](https://grid.layoutit.com/), where you'll be able to design tables using the grid layout display.

Comment: Can you add a small and simple example for your advise? This way your answer will greatly help people that haven't used grid layout before.

Comment: Thanks, i'm actually fooling around with this right now and it's a heck of a lot easier to edit things per cell versus what I was doing before.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. I think the code may still be garbage but seems to be doing what I want it to https://jsfiddle.net/dm12unga/1/ There's proper spacing between the cells and when putting mouse of cell 4 and 6, the little menu comes up with text

Answer (score 0):

## Try with below code. Where I have made changes.

```
//CSS       
 .BestSellerCell {
            /* display: table-cell; */
            border: 1px solid #ececec;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 21px;
            float: left;
            height: 200px;
        }
    
       .BestSellerCell:hover{
          background-color:red;
        }
        
    .child-span{display:none;}

//HTML -- for each div I have added the child span
<div class="BestSellerCell"><span class="child-span">child span</span> This is just a quick test </div>

//Script -- I have added the mouse event 

           $('.BestSellerCell').mouseenter(function(){
              $(this).find('.child-span').show(); 
            });
            $('.BestSellerCell').mouseleave(function(){
              $(this).find('.child-span').hide(); 
            });
```

Comment: I just put this into jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to bring up the text on hover. I don't know if im entering it in correctly. It just seems to turn the cell red

Comment: you have to keep text in <span>tooltip text</span> and hide it from css initially, you can show with the help of script code which mention above in mouse event.